# public E remove(int index) How to remove index from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

ok I have this code that someone helped with me

```
public void add(int index, E element)
        if (index < 0 || index >= mList.length){   
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();  // check if index is ok.
        }
        Object[] temp = new Object[mList.length + 1];  // create the new array into temp.
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < temp.length; ++i, ++j){  // loop into the array by comparing the first array to the second array's index i&j
            if ( i == index ) {  // check if i is valid
                temp[index] = element;  // insert element into the array
                --i; // decrement original array to cancel out j temp array
            } else {
                temp[j] = mList[i]; // 
            }
        }
        mList = temp;
    }
```

Now I need to

```
    public E remove(int index)
```

Do I need to create a temp array again?

I know there are two arrays, do I just do a for loop on the current array which is temp?

Comment: Wait, two arrays? Where?

Comment: If you want to shrink the array, then yes.

Comment: This, IMO, is unnecessarily complicated. Both `add()` and `remove()` can be easily implemented in terms of `System.arraycopy()` and `Arrays.copyOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a way similar to your add, then yes, you need a temp array.

```
public E remove(int index) {
  Object[] temp = new Object[mList.length + 1];
  for (int i = 0; j < mList.length; ++i) {
    if(i<index) temp[i]=mList[i];
    if(i>index) temp[i-1]=mList[i];
    //N.B. not added if i == index
  }
  mList = temp;
}
```

To sum it up, you don't remove the element from the array, you just don't add it to the new one.

If you want a better solution, you should take a look at `System.arraycopy()` and `Arrays.copyOf()`. Give it a try and if you have difficulties don't shy away from asking.

If you are not *forced* to use arrays, I'd suggest you use Collections. For instance a List would suit your needs very well.

Comment: I know what you mean, but they want us to use basic codes with out the help and use of shortcuts.

Comment: sorry I was distracted, yes we are using collections. But Im still confused on how to remove an index from an array. I know I have to loop around the stored array list and remove..

Comment: @user3659356: I added some code (untested, but you'll get the idea)

Comment: Aha, i see sorry abt not responding. I compared it to what I have, your is so much cleaner and easier to understand. Thank you so much. Not I trying to learn how to thread.

Comment: @user3659356: no problem. If it helped you, you should accept it as the answer by clicking on the green tick next to it.